# Как создать seed, чтобы вставить запись?

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется таблица с полями:

```
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('meta_description');
    $table->string('meta_keywords');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->string('author');
    $table->timestamps();
```

Как мне теперь создать seed, чтобы вставить запись?
Делаю вот так, ничего не происходит:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class blog_table_seeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
            DB::table('blog')->insert([
                'id' => NULL, // Здесь автоинкремент должен быть
                'title' => 'тайтл новости',
                'meta_description' => 'мета описание',
                'meta_keywords' => 'ключевики',
                'image' => 'картинка',
                'description' => 'Описание',
                'author' => 'Автор'
                // Дата создания, я так понял, автоматом заполняется?
            ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'id' => NULL указывть  не надо.
```

Запуск миграций по команде:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

или

```
php artisan db:seed --class=blog_table_seeder
```

и рекомендую классы называть так BlogTableSeeder

Comment: Если запускать через `php artisan db:seed`, то нужно в классе `DatabaseSeeder` в методе `run()` написать такую вещь `$this->call('blog_table_seeder');`

Comment: Да, важное дополнение, спасибо.

Comment: Все работает, а подскажите как сделать так, что бы текущая дата автоматически подставлялась?

Comment: Если laravel-way, то `Carbon::now()`.

документация тут: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, id вам передавать не надо. Он подставится автоматически.

Во-вторых, файл сидера, как и класс, лучше называть в формате CamelCase.
Имя файла должно совпадать с именем класса.

В-третьих, если вы создали сидер вручную, выполните в консоли команду

```
composer dump-autoload
```

находясь в папке с проектом.

Не забудьте выполнить миграцию командой

```
php artisan migrate
```

Чтобы сидировать базу данных выполните команду

```
php artisan db:seed --class=blog_table_seeder
```

---

Чтобы ваш данные из вашего сидера попали в базу данных без указания класса по команде

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Необходимо, чтобы в папке с сидерами был файл `DatabaseSeedeer.php` следующего содержания:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Для Laravel 5.1
        $this->call(blog_table_seeder::class);

        // Для Laravel 4.2 заменить на
        // $this->call('blog_table_seeder');
    }
}
```

---

Метод `insert` не подставляет дату автоматически.

Есть два решения.

#### Первое решение через вставку данных в сидере:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class blog_table_seeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('blog')->insert([
            'title' => 'тайтл новости',
            'meta_description' => 'мета описание',
            'meta_keywords' => 'ключевики',
            'image' => 'картинка',
            'description' => 'Описание',
            'author' => 'Автор',
            // заполняем timestamps вручную
            'created_at'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### Второе решение через добавление и использование модели:

`Blog.php`

```
<?php

// На этом этапе будьте внимательнее с namespace

class Blog extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'blog';
}
```

`Ваш сидер.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
// На этом этапе будьте внимательнее с namespace

class blog_table_seeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // метод create автоматически заполнит timestamps
        Blog::create([
            'title' => 'тайтл новости',
            'meta_description' => 'мета описание',
            'meta_keywords' => 'ключевики',
            'image' => 'картинка',
            'description' => 'Описание',
            'author' => 'Автор'
        ]);
    }
}
```